# two onclick events on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code below on the same page the problem im having is that whenever I click stream stream 2 it still opens page1 instead of page2 this my first time using code like this so im still learning.

```
<a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;padding:10px; background: #18da07" 
   href="page.htm"
   onClick="window.open('page.htm','page','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">Stream 1</a>
<noscript>
    <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;padding:10px; background: #18da07" href="page.htm" target="_blank">Stream 1</a> 
</noscript>&nbsp;
<a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;padding:10px; background: #18da07" 
   href="page2.htm"
   onClick="window.open('page2.htm','page2','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">Stream 2</a>
<noscript>
    <a style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;padding:10px; background: #18da07" 
       href="page2.htm" target="_blank">Stream 2</a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: your code seems okay to me http://jsfiddle.net/Lneu8arb/, can you elaborate a bit more, or reproduce the problem on jsfiddle so other can see the problem easier

Comment: it seems fine, but window.open should not be used, please use: `target="_blank"`

Comment: I would have done what you suggested I just couldn't get it to open the window in specific size that way I fixed the code but I have no idea how I got it to work

Comment: Actually when I Posted the question  someone edited the post Im guessing a moderator did anyway I copied the code after it was edited and it worked maybe I had a space or something somewhere that was causing the problem